# Is there any way to create an instance for current class type dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift

Assume that I have more than 10 classes, for example: class1, class2, class3, .. etc and each class has own functions.

My question is, since I have to create an instance for each class to use its functions, can I create an instance variable dynamically and assign class type rather than to specific the type manually?

I mean something like this:

```
class class1 {
    static var instance = self
// or
    static var instance :type(of:self) {
        get {
            return type(of:self)
        }
    }
}
/* instance type will be "class1", through "instance" I can access to class public functions */
```

Of course I tried these ideas but none of them worked.

Is there any way to do it?

UPDATE :

```
class Country {
      static var instance = Country()

      func do_something1 () { // do soething
      }
      func do_something2 () { // do soething
      }
      func do_something3 () { // do soething
      }
      func do_something4 () { // do soething
      }
      func do_somethingN () { // do soething
      }

  }
```

I want make `instance` got it type dynamically based on class that exist in rather then specific type manually

Comment: Why *exactly* do you need to do that? Explain your problem more.

Comment: It's not a problem, It just a question for reduce the code work @RobertDresler

Comment: if you want you can make it as protocols and delegates and implement that delegates methods in your derived class, using this no need to create instances for accessing methods or functions and more over you can write your method implementation in your derived class

Comment: @Mesh again, if you want to get answer how to reduce your code, provide more details

Comment: @RobertDresler Update added

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class by providing class name and then you can init.

```
func classFromString(className: String) -> AnyClass! {
    let namespace = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleExecutable"] as! String;
    let class1: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("\(namespace).\(className)")!;
    return class1;
}
```

Comment: thank you for helping, but i'm looking for return class exist in